# Using table inside of dynamic step definitions

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, cucumber, watir

I have feature file with step like this

```
When user login with credentials
|username|password|
|blahblah|blahblah|
```

But then I want to use this step inside my dynamic step definitions. Is it possible? I was trying to do something like this

```
step 'user login with credentials
    |username|password|
    |blahblah|blahblah|'
```

or creating and passing a hash. Couldn't make it work so far.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions#calling-steps-with-multiline-step-arguments

Calling steps with multiline step arguments

Sometimes you want to call a step that has been designed to take Multiline Step Arguments, for example:

```
# ruby
Given /^an expense report for (.*) with the following posts:$/ do |date, posts_table|
  # The posts_table variable is an instance of Cucumber::Ast::Table
end
```

This can easily be called from a plain text step like this:

```
# feature
Given an expense report for Jan 2009 with the following posts:
  | account | description | amount |
  | INT-100 | Taxi        |    114 |
  | CUC-101 | Peeler      |     22 |
```

But what if you want to call this from a step definition? There are a couple of ways to do this:

```
# ruby
Given /A simple expense report/ do
  step "an expense report for Jan 2009 with the following posts:", table(%{
    | account | description | amount |
    | INT-100 | Taxi        |    114 |
    | CUC-101 | Peeler      |     22 |
  })
end
```

Or, if you prefer a more programmatic approach:

```
# ruby
Given /A simple expense report/ do
  step "an expense report for Jan 2009 with the following posts:", table([
    %w{ account description amount },
    %w{ INT-100 Taxi        114    },
    %w{ CUC-101 Peeler      22     }
  ])
end
```